# How to bind html button with a post request in Python (Aiohttp)?

Tags: html, aiohttp, python-3.9

I developing a small project for testing aiohttp and faced a problem. I have an html file with an input form and one input type="submit". Meanwhile, I've created "post" and "get" requests in Views of my project, where "get" shows the html page, and "post" writes data about user to the database. I've checked "post" separately (using Postman) and it works fine. But when I click "Register" button it doesn't call "post" function. How to bind them?

**File main.py**

```
import aiohttp_jinja2
import jinja2
from aiohttp.web import Application, View, run_app
from aiohttp.web_response import Response
from aiohttp_jinja2 import template
import os


@template('add_user.html')
async def add_user_handler(request):
    return {'path': os.getcwd()}


class AddUserView(View):
    async def post(self):
        ### here I put data to the database
        print('example')
        return Response(text='Everything is ok!')

    async def get(self):
        response = await add_user_handler(self.request)
        return response


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = Application()

    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('./'))
    app.router.add_view('/add_user', AddUserView)
    run_app(app)
```

**File add_user.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add user page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center">
        <h2> Hello, this is the register page!</h2>
        <p>Put your data here:</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" maxlength=30 minlength=3 placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="post" value="Register"><br>
        <p>{{path}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your form with the `form` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="/add_user">
  <p>Put your data here:</p>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="post" value="Register"><br>
</form>
```